# How to pass login parameters in the artillery.io request

Tags: artillery

I have started using 'Artillery.io for load testing. Here how to pass authentication parameters like `email, password` in the `load-test.yml`, the below throws `401` an unauthorised error while sending the request. Could someone guide me on how to pass authentication parameters like `email and password`

```
config:
  target: 'https://test-url.com'
  phases:
    - duration: 70
      arrivalRate: 10
  defaults:
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json

scenarios:
  - flow:
    - get:
        url: /findAMembership
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
    - post:
        url: /auth
        body:  '{"username":"test@test.com", "password": "some_testpassword"}'
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Where is the `401` coming out from? `/findAMembership` or `/auth`?

Comment: Its from `url: /auth`, does the rest of the above `load-test.yml` looks ok though ?  is there any missing details ?

Comment: I have assumed the `auth` method in my answer, but for more accurate, please specify the method your authentication endpoint is using.

Comment: Have you solved your problem yet? A quick feedback would be very helpful for other readers.

Answer (score 1):

There are something to do with your script that makes it much easier to read, troubleshoot and maybe solve your problem.

First, about the `401` problem, I think your request does not meet the authentication endpoint requirements. Please check the endpoint. (like how to do the `auth` in a normal way?)

I assume that the endpoint accepts an `json` request (`username` and `password`) and response a `Bearer token`, you can try this (use `json` instead of `body`, and define the `key-value`):

```
- post:
    url: "/auth"
    json:
      username: "test@test.com"
      password: "some_testpassword"
    headers:
      Content-Type: "application/json" # no need this, you have specified the default Content-Type
    capture:
      json: "$.token"
      as: "token" # Should have this, read below
```

And just a note, you sent an `auth` request and do not capture anything from it, which makes no sense. Remember to capture the response (like `Bearer token`, etc.) for chaining requests that need the authentication. [Read more](https://artillery.io/docs/http-reference/#extracting-and-reusing-parts-of-a-response-request-chaining)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the users from file, you can specify a payload path, and it's fields. This also allowed you to test scenarios where you have several users, and/or failed attempts.

```
config:
  target: "<TARGET>"
  payload:
    - path: "./users.csv"
      fields:
        - "username"
        - "password"
      order: sequence
      skipHeader: true
    - path: "./products.csv"
      fields:
        - "id"
      order: sequence
      skipHeader: true
  phases:
    - duration: 60
      arrivalRate: 20
scenarios:
  - flow:
    - post:
        url: "/login"
        json:
          username: "{{ username }}"
          password: "{{ password }}"
```

This way the username and passwords will be read from the specified CSV- file and `POST`ed to the `<TARGET>/login` endpoint with the json body object

```
{ 
  username: <READ USERNAME>
  password: <READ PASSWORD>
}
```

An example CSV- file may look like

```
username,password
some1@example.com,super1
email@example.com,secret
```